# How do I read a "," as "<br />" in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, break

So I have this MySQL database and a table and in the rows there a lot of "," in them, and I wish when they are output on the screen with PHP to be switched to "
" instead of coma, how do I do that?

I mean, this is a example, it stands like this: hello,no,thanks and instead of being output like that I would like it to be output as: 
hello
no
thanks

How do I do that? Could someone do it for me? Would be very friendly.

Comment: -1 for rolling back your question twice without an explanation of *why* or any better specifics as to **what you actually want**. We can't help you if you don't help us.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no CSV quoting issues:

```
$newStr = str_replace( ',', '<br>', $string );
```

EDIT:

After seeing your rollback, i see that you actually want to replace the `,` with a `newline` character such as `\r`, `\n` or `\r\n`:

```
$newStr = str_replace( ',', "\n", $string );
```

Comment: @Anne, whoops, thanks for catching that. I've been using more JS than PHP recently.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'asdf,asdf';
$str = str_replace(',','<br />',$str);
```

Comment: @Eric: That depends on your code, since I have no idea what it looks like I can't help you

Answer (score 1):

Use `str_getcsv()` to make sure the escaped commas are processed correctly.

**Code:**

```
$input = "hello,no,thanks";
$array = str_getcsv($input);
$result = implode("\n",$array);
```

**Output**

```
hello
no
thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a php str_replace.

```
$final_data = str_replace(",","<br />",$row["data"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the MySQL [REPLACE function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) to have the data come back from your query already formatted like this:

Example:

```
select replace(column_with_commas_in_strings,',','<br />') as new_string
from some_table;
```

In your case, something like:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT replace(alias,',','<br />') as ALIAS FROM characters WHERE namn = 'Jargon'");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/de/function.str-replace.php)

```
$my_output = str_replace(",", "<br />", "no,thanks,text,text");
```

Comment: after you get the data from the database. Why someone gave -1 to me? it is just correct.

Comment: @Eric: You put it in your program. Read the description of str_replace that Vural Acar posted a link to and figure out how to integrate that to your existing code. If you are having trouble with that, update your question with the code that is giving you problems and we can help with that.