# How do I read a "," as "<br />" in PHP/MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I read a “,” as “<br />” in PHP/MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6230515/how-do-i-read-a-as-br-in-php-mysql)

This is my code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn = 'Jargon'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class='content_left'>";
  echo "<div class='blue_text_header'>Information</div>";
  echo "<h1>";
  echo $row['Namn'];
  echo "</h1>";
  echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
  echo "<div class='red_text_header'>Obekräftade fall</div>";
  echo " " . $row['unconfirmed'];
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='content_right'>";
  echo "<div class='orange_text_header'>Andra namn</div>";
  echo $row['Alias'];
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
  echo "<div class='green_text_header'>Bekräftade fall</div>";
  echo " " . $row['confirmed'];
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

And the output for "Alias" is for example: hello,no thanks,I don't like you 
but instead I want the output to be like:

hello
no thanks
I don't like you
What I mean is I want to switch every coma for a line break and how do I do that and where do I put the code? I made another question, but I forgot to ask where to put the code, I don't know PHP, most is just copy paste and it's for a project that has to be done 2morrow.

Comment: Please don't repost your question, just edit your old one

Comment: A new question just to ask where to put that line? You don't have to know PHP in order to understand where to put that line.

Comment: I'm very sorry. How do I remove this question? I'm new here so I don't get everything. A lot of things I don understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the str_replace() function.

```
echo str_replace(',','<br />', $row['Alias']);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM characters WHERE namn = 'Jargon'");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<div class='content_left'>";
  echo "<div class='blue_text_header'>Information</div>";
  echo "<h1>";
  echo $row['Namn'];
  echo "</h1>";
  echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
  echo "<div class='red_text_header'>Obekräftade fall</div>";
  echo " " . $row['unconfirmed'];
  echo "</div>";
  echo "<div class='content_right'>";
  echo "<div class='orange_text_header'>Andra namn</div>";
  echo $row['Alias']; <-------------------------------- REPLACE THIS LINE WITH THE NEW CODE
  echo "<br />";
  echo "<br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />";
  echo "<div class='green_text_header'>Bekräftade fall</div>";
  echo " " . $row['confirmed'];
  }

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Comment: Yes, but can you tell me where to put it in my code? That's the part I need help with.

Comment: You replace your line "echo $row['Alias']" with this.

Comment: @Eric: Think about which line you want to replace.

Comment: Thank you a lot! It worked! Who do I give rep and how do I do it?

Comment: Oh and, I have another question, should I make a new question or say it here? I can't self answer my question, should I edit it?

Comment: You can approve an answer as the "approved" answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
$row['Namn'] = str_replace(',', '\r', $row['Namn']);
$row['unconfirmed'] = str_replace(',', '\r', $row['unconfirmed']);
$row['confirmed'] = str_replace(',', '\r', $row['confirmed']);
```

Put this right inside your `while` loop, should get it